# i cant watch youtube livestreams in CefSharp (ChromiumBrowser)

Tags: visual-studio-2019, cefsharp

as I have said in my last post I am working on a CefSharp Browser and I encountered a problem when I try to watch a Livestream it comes up with this error

> "Your browser does not currently recognize any of the video formats
>   available. Click here to visit our frequently asked questions about
>   HTML5 video."

is there any way I can fix this error I'm trying to make my browser feature-packed and would really appreciate the help.

Comment: If the stream uses H264 then it's not supported. See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#multimedia-audiovideo

Comment: Not really, can you give a example project in windows form app net framework

Comment: If I had to guess I'd say it's not supported, so no I cannot give you an example.

Comment: Maybe you can try the new browser control from Microsoft. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/

Comment: i donnt know how to take the browser control form microsoft edge and bring it to my browser. can you tell me

Comment: I've never used it. I maintain the CefSharp project.

Comment: it shows the an object is not set as an instence of an object when i add the webviewcontrol to my project

Comment: i think cefsharp is easyer and plus i cant use the miscrosoft one because if i put it in my real browser project it will mess everything up and my code dosent work with it

Comment: can you give my your cefsharp project if its windows form app

Comment: CefSharp cannot live stream youtube. If that is your requirement then you will need to use a different browser. The new WebView2 from Microsoft is worth considering.

Comment: the link you gave me in one of my questions to help me with How do i make cefsharp use a certin search engine, i read on github when i went to the main homepage of that project you sent me and it says Added HTML5 support and i downloaded it and it let me watch licestreams so why cant i do that

Comment: Open http://html5test.com/ in the ChromiumWebBrowser instance. It's possible you need to enable WebRTC, https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample/blob/cefsharp/83/CefSharp.MinimalExample.WinForms/Program.cs#L47 ask the project owner if anything else is required if that doesn't work.