# How do i make CefSharp Support HTML5 using .NET Framework 4.7.2

Tags: visual-studio-2019, cefsharp, .net-framework-version

i was going to watch a youtube Livestream on my browser I made in visual studio 2019 and when I find a Livestream an error comes up saying that my browser doesn't support HTML5 and i don't know how to fix it. im using a windows form project running .NET Framework 4.7.2 can someone give me a detailed answer with code that I can put in my project

Comment: Does this answer your question? [i cant watch youtube livestreams in CefSharp (ChromiumBrowser)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62316486/i-cant-watch-youtube-livestreams-in-cefsharp-chromiumbrowser)

Comment: Not really, can you give an example project in windows form app net framework

Comment: You've already asked this question, it will likely be removed as duplicate.

Comment: I know, the answer that was given I couldn't understand it

Comment: You shouldn't open a new question.

Comment: ok i wont, sorry about that